# Do I need to create aliased tables in the DSV to support multiple hierarchies hanging off the same table?

Tags: ssas

For example, the table Company sits at the top of every hierarchy, i.e.:

Company > Category > Sub Categeory > Product > Transactions

Company > Type > Product > Transactions

If I simply create a DSV with these 'natural' hierarchies hanging off the Company and then build a dimension with hierarchies, will this arrangement cause me difficulties, i.e. do I need to create Named Queries to alias my Company table in the DSV for each hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You only can create hierarchies on attributes of the same dimension. As long as all attributes (columns) are in the same table/view/named query, there is no need for aliases. If they are not in the same table/view/named query, then you will have to put them into one in the DSV, or in a previous step in the relational database, e. g. via a view.